# Build a Unity asset bundle on linux?

Tags: unity, assets, linux, mono

I'm trying to generate an asset bundle on a remote linux machine and stream the bundle to a running Unity instance.

Is it possible to download the same libraries Unity uses and compile on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, currently Unity3D doesn’t yet support Linux targeted development - only deployment. At the moment, http://unity3d.com/unity/system-requirements states only Windows and Mac versions are available.

There are two main possibilities if you want to use Unity3D:

1. Deploy for Linux from one of the supported systems (you could make a script that would upload it to the test Linux machine for example)
2. IF and only if Unity3D does NO packaging, and I believe it does which would mean this isn't an option, you could use mono. maybe http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html might help? I realize that link is for importing, but it might be useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/desktop
… claims that they only officially support Ubuntu. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't build bundles on the fly from a Unity runtime(linux or otherwise) you can really only use the editor to do this. So essentially you'd update your bundles then load them up to your linux server.

To stream a bundle from a remote server you can do the following (javascript code this is from the docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-assetBundle.html))

```
function Start () {
    var www = new WWW ("http:/myservermyBundle.unity3d");
    yield www;
    // Get the designated main asset and instantiate it.
    Instantiate(www.assetBundle.mainAsset);
}
```

Comment: Running the editor in Batch mode and using command-line arguments you can turn the editor into a service. But this will only work on Windows and Mac